# How to extract PID parameters from a controller in zpk form?

Tags: dynamical-systems, laplace-transform, control-theory, partial-fractions, rewriting-systems

I have a plant of 3th order, e.g.:
$$
G(s)=\frac{5}{(s+2)(s^2+2s+4)}
$$
that I want to control by tracking the reference.
Now I need to have a fast response, zero steady-state error and low overshoot. Which seems like I need to have a pure integrator $\frac{1}{s}$, high bandwidth (0 dB-crossover freq.), hence a high proportional gain, and a high enough phase margin around the bandwidth area. Since the plant rolls off to a phase of $-270^{\circ}$ on its own, and to $-360^{\circ}$ by adding the integrator, I will need three D-actions to place my bandwidth at a high frequency.

The standard form for this controller will be :
$$
C(s)=K_p \frac{\prod\limits_{i=1}^3\left(1+\dfrac{s}{z_i}\right)}{s}
$$

However, I have to take into account that the controller should be proper!
This means I need to add two extra poles elsewhere:
$$
C(s)=K_p \frac{\prod\limits_{i=1}^3\left(1+\dfrac{s}{z_i}\right)}{s\prod\limits_{i=1}^3\left(1+\dfrac{s}{p_i}\right)}
$$

Now my question is as follows:
Since the controller needs to be composed of PID elements, how can I rewrite the controller in terms of PID parameters:
$$
K_p+K_i\frac{1}{s}+K_d\frac{s}{T_fs+1}
$$ , or the other way around?
I need, after all, to have a proper controller that's composed of existing PID parameters. Of course, the controller can be a PIDD, PII etc.. as long as it contains the correct PID terms.

---

Edit: 
I've already found the following relationship. If a controller is of the following form:
\begin{equation}
X(s)=K \frac{(1+z_1 s)(1+z_2 s)}{s(1+p_1 s)}
\end{equation}, then we can rewrite this to the following PID simplification:

\begin{equation}
X(s)=K(z_1+z_2-p_1)+K\frac{1}{s}+K(p_1^2-p_1(z_1+z_2)+z_1z_2)\frac{s}{1+p_1 s}
\end{equation}

Now, this is probably useful information to go from here to the indicated form above.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Do you want to design a PID controller for the plant $G(s)$ or do you want to convert the proposed $C(s)$ to PID form?

Comment: Either way, obtaining PID parameters in an analytic way is generally a dirty approach, as the equations become far more complex.

Comment: I am trying to obtain the PID parameters from the proposed form.

Comment: For now, I can tell that you don't need three $D$ actions to move the bandwidth. The form you wrote is a lead-lag controller

Comment: Maybe not, but my bandwidth wouldn't be optimal. Let's say I use 3 D-actions. How do I get the desired form as shown above?

Comment: You either choose to have three D-actions, (this way you end up with some lead-lag forms) or you continue your design with the standard PID form. You can't get a dog and ask it to lay some eggs.

Answer (score 0):

In general you would want an asymptote of minus one near your bandwidth and minus "many" before and after it. This would already guarantee stability if $G(s)$ is stable and you do not use unstable poles for $C(s)$.

If you want a proper transfer function for the controller, then you can always add addition poles to the controller after the bandwidth frequency.

You are right that you need at least one integrator, because otherwise the steady state error will not go to zero (this also comes down to the minus "many" before the bandwidth).

Comment: I'm sorry, but this doesn't answer my question. I suggest you read my question again.

Comment: @BlueRineS Are you more interested in [partial fraction decomposition](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/partfrac.htm)?

Comment: Might be something like that indeed. But if you know a way that solves my problem, then by all means go ahead.

Comment: @BlueRineS So you first want to design a controller using the product of poles and zeros (your third equation) and translate it into some sort of partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: So yes, my question reads as: how can I rewrite the controller in terms of PID parameters?, as stated above in the OP. Assume I have a controller in the given form (3 zeros, 3 poles), how can I go from there to a form consisting of (multiple) PID elements?

Comment: @BlueRineS But why do you want it in that form?

Comment: Since I need it for a certain assignment. Imagine if you would want to actually implement this controller, you would need to know these parameters. It seems like you somehow try to avoid to answer it in the way I  seek. If you don't know it that's ok, but you don't need to try to change the problem to something it isn't. I want to deal with it as is, and not in some other way.